# Drawable.createFromStream and getResources().getDrawable, why their outputs are different?

Tags: java, android

I've an image of 32x32, which I have put in drawable folder and the same image application downloads from server. But downloaded one looks bigger(more like 48x48) and pixelated.

Server Code ( C# )

```
        MemoryStream tms = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(tms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] imageData = tms.ToArray();
        //send data to phone
```

Application Code ( Java )

```
    ByteArrayInputStream memStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
    Drawable image = Drawable.createFromStream(memStream, ""); //big image and pixelated
    memStream.close();
```

but if I load same file from Resource, its always smaller

```
Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
```

ImageView xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:scaleType="center" />
```

Edit :

Finally, setting the TargetDensity of BitmapDrawable worked!

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
        imageData.length);
BitmapDrawable image = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
image.setTargetDensity(bmp.getDensity());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is rescaled depending on the device's pixel density, try using `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(...)` and wrap it using `new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap)` if you want a Drawable object.

Comment: Same result                                                                     

Drawable image = new BitmapDrawable(
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(memStream));